# Question in proof of Weyl's lemma on harmonic equations

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, elliptic-equations

I'm reading Jost's Partial Differential Equation Chapter 2.
To point out where I'm stuck, here is the excerpt of the textbook dealing with Weyl's lemma.

(The mollifier is defined as $\rho (t) = C exp(\dfrac{1}{t^2-1})$ for $0\le t < 1$, where $C$ is a constant that makes integral of $\rho = 1$ )

[image]

So the red line is where I got stuck. To explain in detail, isn't there a ball $B$ with center in $\Omega_r$ and radius bigger than $r$ (smaller than $R/2$) such that $B\not\subset \Omega$? Even if we confine our ball $B$ to be a subset of $\Omega$, unless $B\subset \Omega_r$ holds, I have no idea why the statement holds.
(Of course if $B\subset \Omega_r$, then $u_r$ is harmonic in there, so the mean value formula holds. In the case $B\subset \Omega$, $u_r$ is not guaranteed harmonic so I've tried direct integration just from the definition but it never worked.)

In the latter part of the proof, author uses family of functions $\{ u_r\}$ and deals uniform boundness and equicontinuity, therefore I suspect the mean value formula should hold for $B\subset \Omega$ in order to make the domain consistent. (Although I don't know how Mean value formula directly implies the uniform boundness. Author explains this by "fix $R$ and let $r\rightarrow 0$", but these $R$ and $r$ caused me confusion from the beginning...)

So I will be extremely grateful if somebody points out the method to make the red-lined statement work. While googling Weyl's lemma, I've seen some references regarding of functional analysis and convolutions, but I don't have any knowledge about those at this moment.

Thank you in advance! Have a nice day :)

Comment: perhaps it should be $0<R/2\le r$?

Comment: But then how can one explain the uniform boundness? (fix $R$ and then take limit $r\rightarrow 0$?